# android proguard apply mapping dynamically in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

A proguard config is shared between java and android project. Java project creates the proguard mapping(e.g., mapping.txt) and Android project needs to apply the mapping. So the mapping.txt can not be applied in proguard.config file since it is shared.

```
-applymapping  /path/mapping.txt
```

For proguard gradle plugin, it can be specified in ProguardTask. Is there a way to do so for android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another file (e.g. proguard-project-android.txt) containing this `-applymapping` rule for the build type in your `build.gradle` where you build your android project (example for release):

```
android {
    ...        
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ....
            proguardFile 'proguard-project-android.txt'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so the proguard file has to be duplicated. They are the same for both except the android one needs to apply the mapping.

Comment: Please read my answer and you will realize that the whole configuration does not have to be duplicated.